# What happened to the network tab in IE diagnostic tools?

Tags: internet-explorer

In IE I'm used to being able to

```
-Press F12
-Click on the Network
-Click on the Play icon
-Navigate somewhere and see the network activity
```

Now all I see is this:

[image]

How do I get to the view I'm used to seeing where I can see all the network activity?

Comment: It is still in the same place for me. It can be a little slow to load at times. Did you give it a bit?

Comment: @JoshMein Yes, but I did find that when I opened the diagnostics on a different webpage it appeared as expected and I was then able to navigate back to the page of interest without any issue. But if I try to open it up from this page it doesn't appear. Very weird.